# Decoding oddball date format with JSONDecoder

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

I'm getting a date format I haven't seen before in a JSON return.

`"/Date(965620800000-0400)/"`

(It's `Mon Aug 07 2000 00:00:00 GMT-0400`)

It is a date value in milliseconds with a GMT offset. I'm attempting to use Swift's native `JSONDecoder` and setting the `dateDecodingStrategy`.

Initially, I tried this:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .millisecondsSince1970
```

As I initially suspected, it didn't work due to the extra non-numeric characters. This was the initial error I got:

> debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data
>   instead.", underlyingError: nil)) The data couldn’t be read because it
>   isn’t in the correct format.

I dug around on [Unicode.org and found this](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns), which says `A` is for milliseconds and `Z` is the ISO8601 basic forrmat with hours, minutes, and optional seconds fields.

With that in mind, I made a `DateFormatter` extension:

```
extension DateFormatter {
    static let nhtsaFormat: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()

        // This is the string that comes back --> "/Date(965620800000-0400)/"

        // These are the formats I tried:
        formatter.dateFormat = "'/Date('AZ')/'"
        // formatter.dateFormat = "'/Date('A')/'"
        // formatter.dateFormat = "'/Date('A`-`Z')/'"
        // formatter.dateFormat = "'/Date('A'-'Z')/'"
        // formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

Over on my `DataManager` class, I changed the `decoder.dateDecodingStrategy` to my custom format, as follows:

```
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(.nhtsaFormat)
```

With each of the various formats, I still get this error:

> debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data
>   instead.", underlyingError: nil)) The data couldn’t be read because it
>   isn’t in the correct format.

I tried removing the problematic date key from my `Codable` struct and I get the right returns, but unfortunately, I need the date, too. Any suggestions how I can decode that string are greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI - `A` is for "milliseconds in day". It is not "milliseconds since some epoch". There is no format specifier that can handle this string.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you! I could bring it in as a string and do a computed var to strip out the extra characters, divide by 1000, crunch the date, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't parse such a date string using a standard `DateFormatter` because there is no standard format specifier representing "seconds (or milliseconds) since epoch". The `A` format specifier is for "seconds in day".

One solution is to use the `.custom` date decoding strategy with a custom method that can parse such a string.

Here is some test code that works:

```
func customDateParser(_ decoder: Decoder) throws -> Date {
    let dateString = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self)
    let scanner = Scanner(string: dateString)
    var millis: Int64 = 0
    if scanner.scanString("/Date(", into: nil) &&
       scanner.scanInt64(&millis) &&
       scanner.scanInt(nil) &&
       scanner.scanString(")/", into: nil) &&
       scanner.isAtEnd {
        return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(millis) / 1000)
    } else {
        return Date() // TODO - unexpected format, throw error
    }
}

let json = "{ \"date\": \"/Date(965620800000-0400)/\" }".data(using: .utf8)!

struct Test: Decodable {
    var date: Date
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom(customDateParser)
let test = try! decoder.decode(Test.self, from: json)
print(test)
```

Note that the timezone offset in the date string is irrelevant. It's not needed to generate the correct `Date` instance.

I've left the error handling as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you! I've learned something really cool! Greatly appreciated.